# Is it a good practice to perform certain initialization code in Fragment constructor

Tags: android

Sometimes, I have some headless fragments, which I need to run some initialization even before `onCreate`

For instance,

```
public class NetworkMonitorFragment extends Fragment {
    public static NetworkMonitorFragment newInstance() {
        return new NetworkMonitorFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    public void init() {
        // This function shall be call even before onCreate.
    }
}

NetworkMonitorFragment networkMonitorFragment = NetworkMonitorFragment.newInstance();
networkMonitorFragment.init();
```

I was wondering, is it a good practice, to have certain initialization inside `Fragment` constructor? Is there any drawback for doing so? The reason I'm asking, because I don't see many code example for doing so.

```
public class NetworkMonitorFragment extends Fragment {
    public static NetworkMonitorFragment newInstance() {
        return new NetworkMonitorFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    public NetworkMonitorFragment() {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        // This function shall be call even before onCreate.
    }
}

NetworkMonitorFragment networkMonitorFragment = NetworkMonitorFragment.newInstance();
```

Comment: This questions seems to better fit the Code Review Plattform. My opinion: when the constructor calls `init()` the user (programmer) will less likely produce the error of calling an uninitialised fragment instance. Forgetting to call a class' `init()` method is a very common error for me. It's good design, if these errors cannot happen.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can, even other methods like `Fragment.instantiate(Context context, String fname, Bundle args)` calls `newInstance()` which calls default constructor. Although you must be aware of some things:

- You **should not do** any stuff that is not independent of fragment's
  state, lifecycle or Android's context
- You **should not do** any stuff that takes up most of the 16ms UI
  drawing window
- You **should not** spawn new threads there

So while variable instantiation or some quick calculations based on external context, let's say, Date, for example, is perfectly fine, but decoding even a small bitmap either synchronously or asynchronously is a quick way to break things.

Answer (score 0):

If execution and results of this function are not tied to fragment lifecycle and not dependent on parent activity then, I guess, it's just a matter of preference.

You can get more specific answers by describing what this function does.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something before fragment created, do it in **onAttach**

(**onAttach** always calls before **onCreate**, [look fragment lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating))

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    init();
    ...
}
```

If you want to sure view is created, do it in **onViewCreated** with same way.